# Bayesian parameter estimation with negative binomial data. No model fit achieved!

Tags: bayesian, modeling, negative-binomial-distribution

**I edited this question to a (hopefully) less confusing structure. The full R code is still available at the end of the post.**

My problem is a bad fit of the parameter n to my data. I will try to shortly explain the steps I have already taken on solving the problem.

My question is, do you suggest that this function I am using is unsuitable for my data, or do I miss anything at the implementation of the model?

```
The rjags model I am working on is this:
model {
 for (i in 1:N) {

y[i] ~ dnegbin (p[i], r)
p[i] <- r / (r + mu[i]) 
mu[i] <- b * n * (1 - exp(-x[i] / n))   # biological meaningful function  

}

r ~ dunif(0,500) 
logit(b) <- logit.b
logit.b ~ dnorm(0.5, 0.00001) 
log(n) <- log.n     # prior for n, parameterized as a normal distribution
log.n ~ dnorm(0, 0.00001)       #
#n ~ dpois(30000)         # alternative prior with poisson distribution

}
```

I run the sampler with 3 chains, 10000 adapt steps, 50000 burn-in steps and 300000 iterations.

I am under the impression, that I am already using the reparameterization by parameters m and r, as J. Kruschke suggest in his blog post from 7th of April 2012. [J. Kruschke blog](http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.de/2012/04/negative-binomial-reparameterization.html)

I also tried to get a better prior on n:

·  I narrowed the mean and variance parameters of the dnorm distribution on the prior for n.

·   I used a truncated normal distribution

·   I tried a poisson distribution

Every time I narrowed the parameter space below a critical point, the posterior distribution of n was highly dependent on the prior. Every time I used an uninformed, broad prior like
log.n ~ dnorm(0,0.00001), the posterior distribution becomes bimodal and contains huge values.

The function I am using has a biological meaning. The b parameter is a proportion of suitable habitats and the n parameter the total number of habitats. It is obvious that the parameter n should not expand to incredibly high numbers.

**This is the old, complete text, with some more details and the data**

I got 36 observations of count data. The data is negativ binomial distributed.
I am using rjags so I used the JAGS code.
The negbin parameter p is derived from the mean of the model (mu) I want to fit to the data and r, which has a uniform prior.
For the model (mu) the parameters b and n use transformed values (logit for b, its a rate) and n (log) to match the normal prior distributions I choose.

The model I choose has a certain meaning in my research context, so I would avoid changing the model, if possible.

My problem is a bad fit of the parameter n!
As you can see in the last plot, the estimated model line does not fit the data at all. I am not shure if I am doing it right by looking at the posterior distributions and HPD for each parameter on it's own. I am under the impression that there has to be a "best fit" joint probability for both parameter together?

```
library(rjags)
library(coda)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
library(faraway)
setwd("R:/desktop")
y<-c(129,1,441,649,121,1,337,5,489,209,1,181,237,273,181,5,1,209,9,221,273,9,77,325,473,269,1,177,233,21,209,93,1,357,89,1)
x <- c(310,10,1210,2410,610,10,1210,10,2410,310,10,610,1210,2410,610,10,10,310,10,610,2410,10,310,1210,2410,1210,10,310,610,10,1210,610,10,2410,310,10)
#---------------------------------------------------------------
modelString ="
model {
for (i in 1:N) {

y[i] ~ dnegbin (p[i], r)  # Likelihood function for data(y), 0 < p < 1,  r natural number without zero, density: ((x+r-1)/x)*(p^r)*(1-p)^x

p[i] <- r / (r + mu[i])  # parametarisation for p[i] (probability of single-success in negbin)
mu[i] <- b * n * (1 - exp(-x[i] / n))  # model function, mu (mean) parameter of p[i]

}

r ~ dunif(0, 500)  # uninformed prior for parameter r (number of success until abort) of the Likelihood function ( a < b; lower = a, upper = b), density: 1/(b-a)
logit(b) <- logit.b
logit.b ~ dnorm(0, 0.00001)  # prior distribution for parameter b, dnorm(mu,tau) tau is the precission = (1/(sd)²)
log(n) <- log.n
log.n ~ dnorm(0, 0.00001)  # prior distribution for n

}
" # close quote for model string

# write modelString to a text file
writeLines( modelString, con = "model1.txt")

#--------------------------------------------------------------

# Set MCMC chain parameters

dataList <- list(
y = y ,
x = x , 
N = length(y))
initsList <- function() list(logit.b = rnorm(1), log.n = rnorm(1), r =runif(1))  # initial values for each parameter and chain. Can be omitted

nChains <- 3  # Number of chains to run the MCMC

adaptSteps <- 10000  # make dependet on number of iterations!!!!!!

burnInSteps <- 50000  # independet of the adaptive phase, but not saved!!!!!!

numSavedSteps <- 300000  # number of saved steps to the coda.samples MCMC output

thinSteps <- 1  # thinning interval for monitor

nIter <- ceiling( (numSavedSteps * thinSteps) / nChains)  # number of iterations to monitor

#--------------------------------------------------------------

# Run the chains

parameters = c("logit.b", "log.n", "r")  # parameter to be monitored

# using the jags.model function to run the chains

jagsModel = jags.model("model1.txt", data = dataList, inits = initsList, n.chains = nChains, n.adapt = adaptSteps)

# Burn-in: (this is a number of not-saved itereations, independet of the adaptive phase)

cat("Burning in the MCMC chain")  # text output
update(jagsModel, n.iter=burnInSteps)  # n.iter is set above

# Now the saved MCMC chain is running

cat("Sampling final MCMC chain")  # text output
codaSamples = coda.samples(jagsModel, variable.names = parameters, n.iter = nIter)

#--------------------------------------------------------------
#
#Backtransformation of the mcmc.list object

codaResults <- codaSamples
for(i in 1:3){
codaResults[[i]][,1] <-    exp(codaResults[[i]][,1])
codaResults[[i]][,2] <- ilogit(codaResults[[i]][,2])
dimnames(codaResults[[i]])[[2]][1] <- "n"
dimnames(codaResults[[i]])[[2]][2] <- "b"
}
coda_sum <- summary(codaResults)

#-------------------------------------------------------------

#Plot results

gelman.plot(codaResults)

densplot(codaResults)


data_plot <- data.frame(y,x)
xx <- 1:2600
b1 = coda_sum$statistics[2,1]       #mean for parameter b
n1 = coda_sum$statistics[1,1]       #mean for parameter n
curveP <- data.frame(xx = xx, y1 = b1 * n1 * (1 - exp(-xx / n1)))

plot_P <- ggplot(data_plot, aes(x = x)) +
ggtitle(" curve fit to count data") +             
geom_point(aes(y = y), colour = "black", size = 1.5, shape = 21, fill ="black") +
geom_line(data = curveP, aes(y = y1, x = xx), lwd= 0.7, lty= 1) +
labs(x = "density", y= "numbers") +
xlim(0,2600) +
ylim(0,1300) +            #(0,1150) oder (0,200)
theme_bw() +
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=8),
    plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=10, face="plain"),
    axis.title=element_text(size=10,face="plain"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank())+

theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = .5),
    axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = .5))
plot_P
```

PS: I have in total 24 of those kind of data sets. This one is not the only one with such a confusing outcome.

Comment: What may be happening, and I'm speculating here, is that your model is good enough so that the variance of $y$ < the mean of $y|x$.  I tried running a simple linear regression of $y~x$ on your data above and got results indicative of this happening.  If this happens, you'll have trouble with uninformative priors, as the MLE does not exist when the sample variance is less than the sample mean and relatively uninformative priors may not be sufficiently strong to "pull" the peak of the posterior back into the allowed parameter space, writing very loosely.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, as I point out in my edited post, and it led to a highly prior driven posterior distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (apparently) is that you haven't chosen reasonable priors for the model.

As I'm not familiar with the trend you're using, I first did a simple maximum-likelihood estimate (using a Poisson likelihood) to get a sense of reasonable values for the parameters. Then I set priors that would accommodate those parameter values, but made the priors very broad so that they would not bias the posterior.

Your data, along with a smattering of the posterior predictive trends from the MCMC chain, are shown here:
[image]

Here is complete R code, which should run as is.

```
# Original script from http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257742/bayesian-parameter-estimation-with-negative-binomial-data-no-model-fit-achieved
# Extensively modified by John K. Kruschke, 10-March-2017.

graphics.off() # This closes all of R's graphics windows.
rm(list=ls())  # Careful! This clears all of R's memory!

library(rjags)

y <- c(129,1,441,649,121,1,337,5,489,209,1,181,237,273,181,5,1,209,9,221,273,9,77,325,473,269,1,177,233,21,209,93,1,357,89,1)

x <- c(310,10,1210,2410,610,10,1210,10,2410,310,10,610,1210,2410,610,10,10,310,10,610,2410,10,310,1210,2410,1210,10,310,610,10,1210,610,10,2410,310,10)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Find Poisson MLE fit:
fitTrend = function( paramVec , y=y , x=x ) {
  b = paramVec[1]
  n = paramVec[2]
  mu = b * n * ( 1 - exp( -x / n ) )  
  neglogpy = -sum( dpois( y , mu , log=TRUE ) )
  return( neglogpy )
}
b = 1.0 ; n = 200 # initial values for search
optimInfo = optim( c(b,n) , fitTrend , x=x , y=y )
bOpt = optimInfo$par[1]
nOpt = optimInfo$par[2]
# Plot data with best fitting trend:
plot( y~x )
xcomb = seq( min(x) , max(x) , length=501 )
lines( xcomb , bOpt * nOpt * ( 1 - exp( -xcomb / nOpt ) )  , col="skyblue" )
title( main=bquote(list(b==.(bOpt),n==.(nOpt))) )
# Implication: Make sure that prior on b,n is appropriate for best fitting
# values. My understanding is that both b and n must be positive, so I'll use
# gamma priors with modes near the best fit values, and wide standard
# deviations.
# Function for finding dgamma parameters from DBDA2E-utilities.R, see
# https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/software-installation
gammaShRaFromModeSD = function( mode , sd ) {
  if ( mode <=0 ) stop("mode must be > 0")
  if ( sd <=0 ) stop("sd must be > 0")
  rate = ( mode + sqrt( mode^2 + 4 * sd^2 ) ) / ( 2 * sd^2 )
  shape = 1 + mode * rate
  return( list( shape=shape , rate=rate ) )
}
nGammaPrior = gammaShRaFromModeSD( mode=nOpt , sd= nOpt/2 )
nSh = nGammaPrior$shape
nRa = nGammaPrior$rate
bGammaPrior = gammaShRaFromModeSD( mode=bOpt , sd= bOpt/2 )
bSh = bGammaPrior$shape
bRa = bGammaPrior$rate
#---------------------------------------------------------------
modelString ="
  model {
  for (i in 1:N) {
    # Likelihood 
    y[i] ~ dnegbin( p[i] , r )
    # re-parametarization for p[i]: See
    # http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2012/04/negative-binomial-reparameterization.html
    p[i] <- r / ( r + mu[i] )  
    # Trend function:
    mu[i] <- b * n * ( 1 - exp( -x[i] / n ) )  
  }
  # Prior:
  r ~ dgamma( 0.1 , 0.1 )
  b ~ dgamma( bSh , bRa )
  n ~ dgamma( nSh , nRa )
}
" # close quote for model string
# write modelString to a text file
writeLines( modelString, con = "model1.txt")
#--------------------------------------------------------------
dataList <- list(
  y = y ,
  x = x , 
  N = length(y),
  bSh = bSh ,
  bRa = bRa ,
  nSh = nSh ,
  nRa = nRa )
#--------------------------------------------------------------
nChains <- 3  # Number of chains to run the MCMC
adaptSteps <- 1000  # make dependet on number of iterations!!!!!!
burnInSteps <- 1000  # independet of the adaptive phase, but not saved!!!!!!
numSavedSteps <- 10000  # number of saved steps to the coda.samples MCMC output
thinSteps <- 1  # thinning interval for monitor
nIter <- ceiling( (numSavedSteps * thinSteps) / nChains)  # number of iterations to monitor
parameters = c("b", "n", "r")  # parameter to be monitored
jagsModel = jags.model( "model1.txt", data=dataList, 
                        n.chains=nChains, n.adapt=adaptSteps )
cat("Burning in the MCMC chain")  # text output
update(jagsModel, n.iter=burnInSteps)  # n.iter is set above
cat("Sampling final MCMC chain")  # text output
codaSamples = coda.samples(jagsModel, variable.names = parameters, n.iter = nIter)
mcmcMat = as.matrix( codaSamples )

# IMPORTANT: Inspect chain diagnostics here...
# **

#-----------------------
# Plot fit over data:
plot( x , y )
xcomb = seq( min(x) , max(x) , length=501 )
for ( stepIdx in floor( seq(1,nrow(mcmcMat),length=20) ) ) {
  lines( xcomb , 
         ( mcmcMat[stepIdx,"b"] * mcmcMat[stepIdx,"n"] 
         * ( 1 - exp( -xcomb / mcmcMat[stepIdx,"n"] ) ) ) ,
         col="skyblue" )
}
#--------------------------------------------------------------
```